# Error to read json result with php

Tags: php, json

I tried to read this json result :

```
stdClass Object (
    [search-results] => stdClass Object
        (
            [opensearch:totalResults] => 1770323
            [opensearch:startIndex] => 0
            [opensearch:itemsPerPage] => 25
            [opensearch:Query] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [@role] => request
                    [@searchTerms] => gene
                    [@startPage] => 0
                )
            [link] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [@_fa] => true
                            [@href] => http://api.els.com/content/search/scidir?start=0&count=25&query=gene
                            [@ref] => self
                            [@type] => application/json
                        )
                )
        )
    )
```

### my code :

```
$json = file_get_contents($requete); // dans la variable json
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->search-results->link[0]; // (I tried also  : $obj->{'search-results'}->link[0];
```

---

code error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR),
>   expecting ',' or ';' in

I don't understand where is my fault, please, have you an idea ?
Thanks
Jean

Comment: it's too hard to debug your provided source! however your code should works fine https://3v4l.org/3KoRQ

Comment: what's the error when you use `$obj->{'search-results'}->link[0]` ?

Comment: please post your json.

Comment: Pass `true` as second argument to `json_decode`. This way, you'll get an associative array instead of an object (where `dashes` are allowed in keys).

Answer (score 0):

> A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by
>   any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular
>   expression, it would be expressed thus:
>   '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

[Check here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

you use `$obj->search-results->link[0];` . I thinks search-results have problem change the `-` in json to `_` (underline) and check it again.

Answer (score 0):

If `search-result` is fixed object then you can try as :

```
$search = 'search-results'; //declare variable 
echo $obj->{$search}->link[0]; // (I tried also  : $obj->{'search-results'}->link[0];
```